# Using Inspector window for padding

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have made a project for the day, to learn and get more knowledge off the inspect window in chrome. Often I am just guessing around to find a problem. I am working on email newsletters, and is using tables.

I am making two tables that contains some text and a color:[Example Page](http://mimsi.dk/foundation/4-col-color/4-col-color.html). When I go below 596; the red and the green color gets a padding until the text. I would like that it looked like this:

[Image of the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS4Ht.jpg)

Here the green and red color is laying against the below column.

I opended the inspect window, but mostly I am guessing around. So how would other people here attack this problem? I can see that the padding is 0px; Therefore I am stuck.

I am using the Foundation framework, so there is a lot of core CSS.

**HTML**

```
<style>
  /* Original Foundation Stylesheet has not been touched */
  .columns {
    border: 1px solid #333;
  }

  .first--column__color {
    background-color: #cd3f33;
    width: 1%;
  }
  .second--column__color {
    background-color: #5aa23c;
    width: 1%;
  }
  /* Removes 16px left-padding. Used in color columns*/
  table th, table td {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }

  .content-text {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px !important;
  }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <style> -->
  <table class="body" data-made-with-foundation>
    <tr>
      <td class="float-center" align="center" valign="top">
        <center>
          <table align="center" class="container">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table class="row">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <th class="small-12 large-1 columns first first--column__color" style="width:1%;">
                          <table>
                            <tr>
                              <th>
                                <p class="text-left"></p>
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                        <th class="small-12 large-5 columns first content-text">
                          <table>
                            <tr>
                              <th>
                                <h5><strong>This is headline 1</strong></h5>
                                <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                        <th class="small-12 large-1 columns first second--column__color" style="width:1%;">
                          <table>
                            <tr>
                              <th>
                                <p class="text-left"></p>
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                        <th class="small-12 large-5 columns first content-text">
                          <table>
                            <tr>
                              <th>
                                <h5><strong>This is headline 2</strong></h5>
                                <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: It is my first post, so I do not have enough reputation to post more than 1 link. Therefore I link to a fiddle here: I have made a fiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/tknwytpk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're changing table behavior but technically what you have to do is change `th.small-12` to `block` instead of `inline-block`.

```
// @media only screen and (max-width: 596px)

td.small-12, th.small-12 {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

However, you have waaaaay too much `!important` going on. I typically recommend people never use this directive at all and it's all over your stylesheets.

`!important` makes it a pain to make future modifications and frankly you're using it as a crutch instead of learning proper specificity. Don't. Learn to work without it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes I noticed there is a lot of `!important`. But it is in the framework, so I do not want to touch this. The only way that I could change the padding, was to set !important. But maybe there is another way. I j How did you figure through the inspect window, that I had to change this?